# Returning characters from methods

Tags: java

The condition from the method classify() only returns the character 'F' . How do I change the return character using if condition. For example, if the net weekly salary is 2500, it should return 'C'.

```
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter Name: ");
    String name=sc.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Enter Weekly Gross: ");
    double gross= sc.nextDouble();
    double gross1=netWeekly(gross);
    char classy=classify(gross1);
    double bonus = gross*0.085;
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("*****SNOW ENTERPRISES*****");
    System.out.println("Employee Name: "+name);
    System.out.println("Gross Salary: "+gross);
    System.out.println("Bonus: "+bonus);
    System.out.println("Net Weekly Salary: "+gross1);
    System.out.println("Classification: "+classy);
}
public static double netWeekly(double a){
    double net=0;
    net = a/4.5; 
    return net;
}
public static char classify(double net){
    double crah=netWeekly(net);

    char letter='F';
    if(crah>1500&&crah<1999)
        letter = 'A';

    else if(crah>2000&&crah<2499)
        letter = 'B';
    else if(crah>2500&&crah<2999)
        letter = 'C';
    else if(crah>3000&&crah<3499)
        letter = 'D';
    else if(crah>3500&&crah<3999)
        letter = 'E';
    else if(crah>4000)
        return letter = 'F';

    return letter;
}
```

}

Answer (score 4):

None of your conditions match the value 2500 exactly.

Change:

```
else if(crah>2500&&crah<2999)
```

to

```
else if(crah>=2500&&crah<3000)
```

(And similarly elsewhere)

---

[oleg.cherednik's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54309707/3788176) suggestion of using a `Map` may work, but I would suggest an alternative implementation: the division of the numbers only works because the bins are equally-sized, and start on aligned boundaries; it would be awkward to adapt this to different boundaries.

An alternative would be to use a `NavigableMap`, which has the `floorEntry` method to get the next-smallest entry. For example, you can use a `TreeMap`:

```
private static final NavigableMap<Double, Character> MAP;

static {
    Map<Double, Character> map = new HashMap<>();
    // Handles everything less than 1500.
    map.put(Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY, 'F');
    map.put(1500.0, 'A');
    map.put(2000.0, 'B');
    map.put(2500.0, 'C');
    map.put(3000.0, 'D');
    map.put(3500.0, 'E');
    map.put(4000.0, 'F');
    MAP = Collections.unmodifiableNavigableMap(map);
}
```

Then:

```
public static char classify(double net) {
    return MAP.floorEntry(netWeekly(net)).getValue();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forget about `>=` comparison. What about to simplify a little this logic?

```
public static char classify(double net) {
    double crah = netWeekly(net);

    if (crah >= 4000)
        return 'F';
    if (crah >= 3500)
        return 'E';
    if (crah >= 3000)
        return 'D';
    if (crah >= 2500)
        return 'C';
    if (crah >= 2000)
        return 'B';
    if (crah >= 1500)
        return 'A';

    return 'F';
}
```

or even like this:

```
public static char classify(double net) {
    return MAP.get((int)netWeekly(net) / 500 * 500);
}

private static final Map<Integer, Character> MAP;

static {
    Map<Integer, Character> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(0, 'F');
    map.put(1500, 'A');
    map.put(2000, 'B');
    map.put(2500, 'C');
    map.put(3000, 'D');
    map.put(3500, 'E');
    map.put(4000, 'F');
    MAP = Collections.unmodifiableMap(map);
}
```